How to restrict a contextual menu to a single collectionView
I have a view with three collection views on it. I want one of the collection views to have a contextual menu. How do I control that only one of them has the menu? In the code below, I have commented out the lines that I'm trying to use to restrict which collection view has the menu.
If I uncomment these lines and try to restricted the menu to just the list_CollectionView_Outlet, I get the error that it's missing a return. "Missing return in instance method expected to return 'UIContextMenuConfiguration?'
It's driving me bonkers what am I doing wrong?
extension Case_VC2: UICollectionViewDelegate
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration?
    {
        //        if collectionView == list_CollectionView_Outlet
        //        {
        gID = theCurrentArray[indexPath.row].ID
        name = theCurrentArray[indexPath.row].Name
        
        let configuration = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { [weak self] _ in
            
            let edit = UIAction(title: K.Titles.edit, image: UIImage(named: "Edit2")) { _ in
                gHideBackBtn = false
                gTheDisabledCell = ""
                self?.addEditTrick()
            }
            
            let remove = UIAction(title: K.Titles.remove, image: UIImage(systemName: K.Icons.trash)) { _ in
                self?.delete_XRef_Item()
            }
            
            return UIMenu(title: "", image: nil, children: [edit, remove])
        }
        
        return configuration
        //    }
    }
}


At the start, where those two commented-out lines are, check that you have the right collection view like this:
guard collectionView == list_CollectionView_Outlet else {
    return nil
}


But really it would probably be better to have each collection view have its own individual data source and delegate, rather than making them all three share the same single object as their data source and delegate.
